# Fortran formatting output

Tags: formatting, fortran

Let's say I need to write a vector of 100 elements in column form to `.txt` file.
Then I generated another vector of 100 values. How can I open that file, write the new vector next to the old one, and close it?
Can someone give me guidance on formatting output files like a pro? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: It will be far easier to assemble a table, each column comprising one of your vectors, in memory and to then write the whole table to file, than it will be to write a file column-by-column.  This is, I assure you, an expert (albeit brief) guide to writing output to files like a pro.  Without the context that your existing code provides it's very difficult to provide more useful guidance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Then, provide us more information about your specific case, preferably show us a [mcve] and describe the desired result you seek, what you've tried and what gone wrong.